# C++ String - Out of scope error

Tags: c++, string

I was trying to play around with Strings in a Hangman program that I'm writing and couldn't get them to work so tried working with them on a simpler basis and I'm still having no luck.

As far as I've read online in the references and what other people have said this code should work:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char** argv){

  string word = {"Hello"};
  int length = strlen(word);

}
```

But I get this compiler error:

'string' was not declared in this scope

and consequently, 'word' is also not declared in scope.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong? I'm using the g++ compiler on Ubuntu if that makes a difference, no idea which version though.

Comment: hmmm... perhaps `#include <string>` would help?

Answer (score 7):

**You are confusing C and C++.**

You included only C libraries, whereas `std::string` comes from the C++ header `string`. You'd have to write:

```
#include <string>
```

to use it. However, you'd then have to make other changes, such as not using `strlen`.

You should learn from your C++ book, not random posts on the internet (*#lolirony*)

---

#### C version

```
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
  const char* word    = "Hello";
  const size_t length = strlen(word);  // `size_t` is more appropriate than `int`

  return 0;
}
```

#### C-like C++ version

```
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  const char* word    = "Hello";
  const size_t length = strlen(word);
}
```

#### Idiomatic C++ version (recommended)

```
#include <string>

int main()
{
  const std::string word   = "Hello";
  const std::size_t length = word.size();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. The confusion is coming from my lecturer, that's how he's been teaching us C++ so far.

Comment: Believe it or not, but I have already seen people overloading `size_t strlen(const std::string& s);` ;D Would probably take a better man than me to tell why... perhaps for templates that work on both `char*` and `std::string`?

Comment: @user2171122: That's unfortunate, because he's teaching it _so_ wrong that it wouldn't even compile.

Answer (score 4):

> 'string' was not declared in this scope

You need to include the header `<string>` and refer to it as `std::string`. Also, `strlen` does not understand `std::string` or any user defined types, but you can use the `size()` method instead:

```
#include <string>

int main()
{
  std::string word = "Hello";
  size_t length = word.size();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[`<cstring>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstring) is the header for C++ support of C-style null-terminated strings. You should include [`<string>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/string).

Answer (score 1):

You haven't included the C++ string header in your project.

```
#include <string>
```

The libraries that you've included are all plain-C headers.

Additionally, `strlen()` doesn't work with a c++ string; you should use `word.size()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

`string` is a specialization of standard class `std::basic_string` . It is declared in header `<string>`

So if you want "to play around with standard class std::string:" you need to include directive

```
#include <string>
```

Header `<cstring>` is not the same as header `<string>` and contains declarations of standard C functions such as `strlen`.

However there is no any sense to apply function `strlen` to an object of type `std::string` The compiler in this case will issue an error.

I advice you to play with the following code that to see the difference

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{

   std::string word = "Hello";
   std::string::size_type length = word.length();

   std::cout << "Object word of type std::string has value "
             << word << " with length of " << length
             << std::endl;
   std::cout << "The size of the object itself is " << sizeof( word ) << std::endl; 

   char another_word[] = "Hello";
   size_t another_length = std::strlen( another_word );

   std::cout << "Object another_word of type char [6] has value "
             << another_word << " with length of " << another_length
             << std::endl;
   std::cout << "The size of the object itself is " << sizeof( another_word ) << std::endl; 
}
```